# Adding Li elements in for loop of JSP but li a:first , last or nth child gives always last element

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I am new to Jquery and CSS . I am trying to add li elements based on some condition in JSP -for loop as below:

```
<ul id="my-criteria-list" >
<%        
for( int i = 0 ; i < mychoices.length ; i++ )
{
  if( i > 0 )
  { 
  %>
   <li class="divider">|</li>  
  <%
  }%>
  <li class="my-criteria"><a href="Landing Page" onclick="goTo(this);"><%=mychoices[i])%></a></li>
    <%
}
  %>       
</ul>
```

MyChoices length is 4 and JSP page display all li elements correctly. But when I do

```
 $('li a:first-child').trigger('click');
```

or even

```
 $('li a:nth-child(1)').trigger('click');
```

only last element is selected. So that means there is only one element in `<LI>`? I need to trigger click for first `<LI>` element. Any help /suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is selecting the first child `a` instead a parent `li`.  What you want to do is select the first child `li` inside parent `ul` instead, and then select and click the `a` inside that.

Try this:

```
$('ul#my-criteria-list li:first-child').find("a").trigger('click');
```